# How can I fix my problem with PostMessageW

Tags: c#, windows

I'm trying to use PostmessageW for a little script I'm trying to make but if notepad is selected as window it doesn't post my letter F.

```
        {
            _ = FX.PostMessageW(_windowHandle, FX.WM_KEYDOWN, 'F', 0);
            FX.Sleep(tijd);
            _ = FX.PostMessageW(_windowHandle, FX.WM_KEYUP, 'F', 0);
        }
```

here is where I call my window

```
fixed (char* ptr = "Naamloos - Kladblok")
            {
                _windowHandle = FX.FindWindowW(null, (ushort*)ptr);
            }

            if (_windowHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                throw new Exception("Window niet gevonden");
            }
```

If I send the code to a friend of mine it works for him, But it doesn't work for me.
Can someone help me with my problem? Thanks

Comment: What is the declaration for `PostMessageW`

Comment: Out of interest, what happens if you change `ptr` to `"Naamloos - Kladblok\0"`?

Comment: @GovindParmar it stays the same doesn't post anything, But the weird thing is it presses something because if i select files in notepad then u hear the windows sound if u pressed something in that tab.

Comment: @Charlieface https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-postmessagew thats what i used as reference

Comment: I understand, but what is your full `DllImport` declaration

Comment: [You can't simulate keyboard input with PostMessage](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050530-11/?p=35513).

Comment: @IInspectable yes u can! A friend of mine used my code on his pc and it works for him but not for me

Comment: *"I have working code that doesn't work"* isn't very convincing. Anyway, I posted the link so that you can educate yourself on the consequences of trying to fake keyboard input by throwing about messages. If you need to inject input, use `SendInput`. If you need to automate an application, use UI Automation.